# Compatibility of getContext and getResource between 5.0 and lower

Tags: android, xml, if-statement, android-manifest

Hi so I released my app a few months ago and it all was working fine and to a degree it still does. On devices running lower than android 5 everything is fine. But I tested on a 5 device today and my if statements are not working. For example it marks every answer as incorrect yet on a lower device the correct incorrect answers is working as intended. I know my code works but I can't work out why it doesn't work on android 5. The only thing I can think of is that i've missed something out on my manifest.

**EDIT: WORKING ANSWER allows compatibility between <=4.0 and 5.0=<:**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            if (Word1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(Word1.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img1).getConstantState())}}

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {        
                             if  (Word1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(Word1.getContext().getDrawable( R.drawable.img1).getConstantState())}}  });
```

Comment: can you post an example of an IF statement that's not working?

Comment: I have added an if statement. But i know the if statement works but for some reason on android 5 it's not. I have a video of the same code working if needs be

Comment: can you try comparing the objects using `.equals` instead of `==`

Comment: not working on marshmallow :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.equals` to compare the objects.

`==` check if it's the same object not if the objects hold the same value, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387742/compare-two-objects-with-equals-and-operator)

Your code shoud look like:

```
if(Word1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.img9).getConstantState())
```

Comment: Are you sure you replaced ALL the == by equals? because normaly it shouldn't work when you compare with ==, maybe this was tolarated someway in earlier version and it's not anymore

Comment: Ok I have changed the == to .equals (i agree this is a better method) but the same problem persists. On my 5.0 devices the if simple goes straight to the fail. But when I test on my 4.0 devices it all works as planned like before. Any idea why an if statement would be ignored like this?

Comment: @Phil3992 any reason you are comparing the `ConstantState` instead of the `Drawable` itself?

Comment: While this wasn't the excat answer the .equals was a big help. The actual problem lies with .getResources this works for 4.0 but .getcontext is needed for 5.0

Comment: Found a solution that should work for all versions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44633363/458365